# Static analysis tool that catches dangerous captures

Tags: c++, code-analysis

In C++11, programmers are given control over how lambdas capture values: each value used in the lambda expression (other than the arguments to the lambda itself) is captured either by reference or by value.

There are a couple of dangers here:

- Capturing a temporary value by reference is not only legal, it fails to produce a compile warning even in the latest versions of GCC and Clang. This will, of course, cause a segfault as soon as the lambda is called.
- Capturing a raw pointer by value may not be any safer than capturing it by reference, since the lambda has no control over the lifecycle of the pointed-to object. This is particularly dangerous when calling function methods inside a lambda, because there is no easy way to guarantee that the `this` pointer will still be valid.

Is there a static analysis tool that catches one or both of these cases? I'd expect the first problem to be pretty easy to catch, but it appears that `clang-check -analyze` (the only static analysis tool I've been able to try on my codebase so far) does *not* catch it.

A Windows tool would be acceptable, even if it requires an MSVC license, but I'd prefer something that can run on Debian Linux.

Comment: I'm not sure it matches your request but, for your first point, I think Viva64 can help you: https://www.viva64.com/en/w/v788/

Comment: @AlexPlacet That does look interesting! I think the error cases referred to are kind of the opposite of what I'm talking about here, though, since the fix is to capture by *reference*.